# Comment exprimer que quelque chose « hit(s) the spot » ?

Tags: expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Pendant mes vacances dans mon pays natal, il m'est souvent arrivé de manger quelque chose qui m'avait manqué. La première chose qui vient à l'esprit dans ces moments là est l'expression anglaise que quelque chose « hits the spot ».

Pour ceux qui ne la connaissent pas, on peut exprimer un sentiment similaire avec, par exemple

> Ah ça fait du bien (+ ça fait longtemps que je ne l'ai pas mangé, ça m'a trop manqué)

Mais on voit tout de suite que cette traduction est un peu lourde. Je cherche donc un équivalent en français.

Je tiens à préciser la différence entre « hits the spot » et « ça fait du bien » : quand quelque chose « hits the spot » il s'agit d'un manque ou un désir très précis. Un exemple en anglais si je peux me permettre :

> Nothing hits the spot after a long day of hard work like a cold glass of water on the porch in the evening.

Comment: @Graffito Effectivement, « ça fait du bien » est peut-être l'expression la plus proche. J'aurais dû ajouter que "hit the spot"est surtout employe quand on parle de nourriture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Comme on peut le voir [ici](https://fr.glosbe.com/en/fr/hit%20the%20spot), il n'y a rien d'idiomatique
> correspondant à l'expression anglaise. Dans le sens d'atteindre la
> cible, on peut « faire mouche ». En argot, « C'est de la balle »
> (Super! Génial!) exprime le sentiment de satisfaction. ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53637/comment-exprimer-que-quelque-chose-hits-the-spot#comment114108_53637))

Answer (score 4):

> *that really hits the spot* [food, drink] : c'est juste ce dont j'avais besoin ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/hit/586564) anglais-français en ligne)

Aussi, *(c'est) ce qu'il fallait* quand ça c'est déjà produit ou *ça ferait vraiment l'affaire, ce serait parfait* pour ce qui est projeté. Le sens de haute adéquation est davantage reflété par le haut degré de l'adjectif et des phrases reliées à l'idée de convenir et au besoin qu'à ce qu'« accomplit » la chose pour ainsi dire.

Comment: Exactement ce qu'il me fallait

Answer (score 3):

Moi je dirais *pile poil*, en langage familier.

> [pile-poil](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/pile-poil) adv    familier (exactement, parfaitement).
>
> C'est pile-poil ce que je cherchais !
>
> C'est pile-poil ce qu'il me fallait !

Answer (score 1):

"Il n'y a rien de tel" peut aussi convenir :

> Nothing hits the spot after a long day of hard work like a cold glass of water on the porch in the evening.

> Il n'y a rien de tel après une longue journée de travail qu'un verre d'eau fraîche le soir sous le porche.

Comment: Ah oui effectivement, merci.